# Postmaster Redirect

Tags: postmaster

Has anyone had this issue and how did they resolve it?

When creating a Parcel and clicking "Save Parcel" it redirects to http://example.com/admin/?/cp/addons_modules/show_module_cp&module=postmaster&method=index&S=39ety0362145b690daab1612312a8509d

This returns a blank page, my site is based from /system not /admin. I see the Parcel is created when I go back into the module but it's funky.  I would ask the dev and have but it seems he may have abandoned his add-ons.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `$config['cp_url']`, under **Admin → System Administration → Config File Editor**. I would guess that you have `http://example.com/admin` in there.

Comment: So strange, I am not even sure how that slipped in there, but sure enough it was there.  It effect nothing else too.  Thanks for your help :)